# Data Science - Average of Rows (numpy) - remove whitespace

Tags: python, numpy

Data Science - Average of Rows

Question:
In a matrix, or 2-d array X, the averages (or means) of the elements of rows is called row means.

Task
Given a 2D array, return the rowmeans.

Input Format
First line: two integers separated by spaces, the first indicates the rows of matrix X (n) and the second indicates the columns of X (p)
Next n lines: values of the row in X

Output Format
An numpy 1d array of values rounded to the second decimal.

```
2 2
1.5 1
2 2.9
```

Sample Output
`[1.25 2.45]`

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
n, p = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
lista = []
for i in range(n):
    lista.append(input().split())
print(np.array(lista).astype(np.float16).mean(axis=1).round(2))
```

Solution fails test case:

```
Input
3 2
1 2
1 0.5
1 0.3
```

Your output:
`[1.5  0.75 0.65]`

Expected output:
`[1.5 0.75 0.65]`

Notice the space before 0.75 means the test case fails. How may I remove the whitespace thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Codingame problem ! Anyway, this seems to be a problem due to round which add extra spaces. A simple solution could be to replace double space by simple space.

```
sol = str(np.array(lista).astype(np.float16).mean(axis=1).round(2))
sol.replace("  ", " ")
print(sol)
```